# Did Frodo lose a finger on Mount Doom?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

In the Return of the King film, Gollum bites the finger off Frodo. In later scenes, like the Coronation of Aragorn and Leaving the Shire, we see that Frodo has gotten the finger back.

How is this possible? How did Frodo get his finger back?

[image]

[image]

Comment: He doesn't, this is an oversight from the film

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well why use a little green sleeve to edit someones finger out for one scene when you would've expect anyone to notice such a minor detail

Comment: It's a prosthetic

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Can you provide some photo or video evidence?

Comment: I would like better photo evidence that he has a finger post Mount Doom. The one provided isn't convincing

Comment: I don't think the second photo shows a full second finger.  His finger was bitten off to the first knuckle.  I think that's visible in the second photo.

Comment: Everyone break into singing the classic song "Frodo of the Nine Fingers and the Ring of Doom"!

Comment: Next up in this tag if the trend continues: *Did the ring really fell into the lava?"

Comment: In case you forgot to words to the song mentioned in @MichaelRichardson 's comment, I found them [here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Frodo_of_the_Nine_Fingers). Remember that since this song is in ballad meter, you can sing it to the tune of Gilligan's Island.

Comment: IN Mount Doom actually.

Comment: Japanese Yakuza are very often using prosthetic little fingers after cutting them off. http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2339321/The-Japanese-prosthetics-maker-reconstructs-fingers-victims-gruesome-yakuza-mafia-tradition.html Apparently, this marvel of the medical industry has reached Middle Earth as well.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

### Yes, he lost his finger

In the film, Frodo loses the top part of his left index finger. The first image in your question proves this, and we can see Gollum discard it in another shot:

[image: Ouchy]

This is notably in contrast to the text, where Frodo loses the [ring finger](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/182228) of his right hand (emphasis mine):

> [Sam] sat up and then he saw that Frodo was lying beside him, and slept peacefully, one hand behind his head, and the other resting upon the coverlet. **It was the right hand, and the third finger was missing**.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Book VI Chapter 4: "The Field of Cormallen"</sup>

### No, he never got it back

In later scenes, we either can't see that finger at all (as in the second image in your question; the left index finger is obscured), or we can see that his left index finger is noticeably stumpy (click to embiggen all images):

- At Aragorn's coronation

  [image]
- At the Green Dragon

  [image] [image] [image]
- At Sam and Rosie's wedding

  [image]
- Writing in his diary

  [image]
- At the Havens

  [image]

That being said, I've heard it claimed that Elijah Wood's finger is visible [later](http://www.moviemistakes.com/entry46075) in the Mount Doom scene, which is possible (though I struggle to see it; I suspect most people would, unless they were specifically looking for it); consider (as always, click to embiggen):

[image]

However, even here it's clear that the intent is to show the finger having been removed; this, as with any later shots where the finger is visible, is just a production mistake.

Comment: "notably in contrast to the text" when it's simply a different hand? :-D

Comment: @motoDrizzt "Top part of left index finger" vs. "entire right ring finger" seems pretty different to me.

Comment: If he didn't lose his finger, it would certainly take away from a lot of story. Especially with Sam being the only hero with sufficient willpower to resist the ring.